# How to fix Android Emulator not responding on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Hey i am new to Android Studio and i just finished the Installation & Configuration but i am facing a problem with the Emulator. When i launch it i get a "XXX.exe is not responding" error from Windows. This is the Event Log:

```
6:13 PM Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this 
machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address 
this in a future release.

6:14 PM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following 
feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSE4.2 POPCNT

6:14 PM Emulator: Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!

6:14 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

6:14 PM Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input 
failed

6:14 PM Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

6:15 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -805306369 
(0xCFFFFFFF)
```

I have tried to Install a new Emulator and changing the RAM of the machine but is not working. How can i fix this?
Thanks for your time!